# Are there any checks for cheating, or is the game based on trust?

Tags: draw-something

I have been playing Draw Something for 24 hours and I have noticed that a few random opponents spell out the answer if they cannot draw it.

This kind of ruins the fun, but I can imagine it would be a very quick way to earn coins which would otherwise cost money, to buy new colour packs.

So my question is, are there any checks in place to stop this? The players who have written out the answer in games against me seem to have got away with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trolling through https://getsatisfaction.com/drawsomething and http://forums.omgpop.com/draw-something there are no *Official Rules* published by OMGPOP.

So, I believe at the time of this post, there are no implementations to mitigate cheating other than the player opting to only draw. Also, there should now be a delete button in the new update, download it and you should be able to delete the games with cheaters.

However I came across this from one of the employees:

> EMPLOYEE Joseph (Official Rep) 1 month ago
>
> Hey David,
>
> Word writing is technically cheating. You should refrain from writing
>   words as much as possible. Try your best to draw out the word without
>   words, it'll be more fun that way :D
>
> Bests  Joe

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any check on this, to the best of my knowledge. I often write notes to my opponent before drawing the word. Particularly if I had a hard time guessing or their drawing was funny. I have quit games with several random people for just writing the letters out. Kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: it does defeat the purpose! however I don't see how the publisher will allow it when people can sit back and cheat for a few minutes to make coins rather than spend real money in the store...

Comment: @AnthonyBlake they should add a 'report user' button. Granted, it would be difficult to keep track of/punish everyone who's been reported, but it might help to serve as an axe hanging over the head

Comment: +1 for Quitting out of games when people write things. I tend ignore it if they write out the word once. If they do it again I'll quit.

Comment: I recently had someone I'd been playing with for about a week start just writing out all the words. It made me sad, but I quit out of that game - why are you even playing, at that point? Coins are pretty worthless once you've got a couple of color packs.

Comment: The Troll thing to do would be start writing words back, but totally unrelated word. For example writing Exciting Princess when the word THEY are supposed to be guessing is Germany. Of course if they are lazy enough to just write the words they'll probably quit.

Answer (score 1):

It is annoying and there are no checks. I am not sure that adding optical character recognition would be worthwhile as it wouldn't even get close to 100%.

The best check on this behavior is that it's actually not that quick of a way to farm coins anyway. Since everything is so expensive, the quicker way would be to play yourself using Facebook and an email account on your phone.

Comment: although we are not of course recommending this

Comment: -1, he's asking how to deal with jerks/cheaters, not how to be a better jerk/cheater.

Comment: @aslum I answered that there was no checking and doing so would be difficult. I then pointed out that writing words is not really that quick of a way to farm coins.